# How to print a Windows Form without showing/displaying it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, printing

I am trying to print automatically a series of Windows-Forms. I don't need to show them. The code examples I found on the internet work only when I display the Form with `show()`! I need to initialize the form with data and send it to the printer Here is the code I am using:

```
public partial class Form2_withoutShow : Form{

     PrintDocument PrintDoc;

     Bitmap memImage;

     public Form2_withoutShow (Data data)
     {

        InitializeComponent();

        /*
           Initialize Data (texboxes, charts ect.) here
       */

        this.PrintDoc = new PrintDocument();
        this.PrintDoc.PrintPage += PrintDoc_PrintPage;
        this.PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
     }


     public void Print()
     {
        this.PrintDoc.Print();
     }

     void PrintDoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
     {

        int x = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.X;
        int y = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Y;
        int width = this.Width;
        int height = this.Height; 

        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(width, height); 

        this.DrawToBitmap(img, bounds);
        Point p = new Point(10, 10);

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, p);
     }

     private void Form2_withoutShow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         // remove TITLEBar
         this.ControlBox = false;
         this.Text = String.Empty;
     }
}
```

I call the `Print()` method from another class in for-loop and pass the Data to be initialized through the constructor.

The MSDN [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6he9hz8c.aspx) captures the part on the screen where the forms should be displayed. This doesn't work for me. The approach I am using now yields only the print of the empty Window if I don't call `show()`. How do I get the data into the form without having to call the `show()` method? Approaches like mimize the windows when displaying it, also don't work because that is also the print result: a minimized window.

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: no I wasn't, my aim was to print protocols, I thought this could be done using a gui populated with data. I ended up creating a PDF using MigraDocs and send this to the printer...

Comment: @ErAcube there is an answer. Did you check it out?

Comment: Yeah thanks for pointing out. I just noticed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before showing the form, the form and its controls are not in [`Created`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.created?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) state. To force the form and its controls to be created it's enough to call internal [`CreateControl(bool fIgnoreVisible)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,9ab3870cc070ff91) method of your form:

```
var f = new Form1();
var createControl = f.GetType().GetMethod("CreateControl",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
createControl.Invoke(f, new object[] { true });

var bm = new Bitmap(f.Width, f.Height);
f.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height));
bm.Save(@"d:\bm.bmp");
```

Also remove codes which you have in your form `Load` event handler, and put them in constructor of your form.

**Note**

There are also other workarounds for the problem:

- For example you can show the form in a location outside of boundary of the screen and then hide it again.  Set the `Location` to `(-32000, -32000)` and set `StartPosition` to be `Manual` then `Show` and `Hide` the form before drawing to bitmap.
- Or as another example, you can show the form with `Opacity` set to `0` and  then `Show` and `Hide` the form before drawing to bitmap.

Comment: In general using reporting tools like `RDLC` reports is more better answer for such requirement; like what you did using a PDF tools, but reports are more friendly. Anyway for learning purpose or for cases which the task should be done by printing the form, I shared this answer with some working options. The first option is preferred.

Comment: Thank you very much for this elaborate answer. Can you explain maybe why the `createControl` method has to be started with `invoke` ? and doesn't work if I simply call `this.CreateControl()` ?

Comment: You are welcome :) The overload which you need is `CreateControl(bool fIgnoreVisible)` which is internal, so even if you want to call it in constructor of that form, you can't.  So the only way to use that method is calling it using [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656691.aspx)

Comment: I made a print method and called it there. It worked with your reflection Approach. I will try it with the overload.

Comment: You can't use that overload without reflection. The overload is internal as mentioned in the answer. The way you did it (like in the answer) is correct. You don't need to change any thing.