# Winforms databinding for invisible controls

Tags: winforms, data-binding, application-settings

I understand that Databinding in Windows Forms only happens to visible controls.

In my code I have multiple tab pages with several controls bounded to settings in ApplicationSettings. Obviously not all controls are visible when the form is opened. The problem is, that these (hidden) controls actual setting is not updated from ApplicationSettings until the user changes at least one of them.

With this behavior I have trouble checking a control state, I simply can't trust it as it may not reflect the last saved state in ApplicationSettings.

What is the way to ensure all control's state is updated from ApplicationSettings ?

Thank you.

Comment: In general it's better to rely on settings values and model values rather than relying on control values. But just for your information, to force the form and its controls to be created and make the data-binding working it's enough to call internal [`CreateControl(bool fIgnoreVisible)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,9ab3870cc070ff91) method of your form. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37888268/3110834).

Comment: Thanks @RezaAghaei, I also figured out that using settings' values is a working approach. However, before using them it is necessary to call Save() on Settings class, otherwise values are not reflecting actual control values. So this is a bit like a snake biting into its tail...