# Save `Window` as pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, telerik, save, window

I have a class, `ReportViewerView`, which inherits the `Window` [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window(v=vs.110).aspx). I want to save the contents of this class to a pdf file.

I can already open that class as a window with `ShowDialog()`, and once opened that window does have an option to save as an Acrobat (pdf) file that works correctly. However, I want to save the contents of that window ***without*** first opening a dialog. I have all the data I need to open this window and I want to save it immediately, to a predetermined file location, without any user input required. How can I do this?

```
public void SaveReport(MyClass report, string title)
{
    ReportViewerView reportViewer = new ReportViewerView(report, title);
    //reportViewer.ShowDialog();

    // is it even possible to make this a byte[] ?
    byte[] reportBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(reportViewer.ToString());
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Temp\\Test_Save.pdf", reportBytes);

    //Maybe a FileStream?
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Temp\\Test_Save.pdf", FileMode.Open))
    {  // Maybe not a TextReader... what would a 'Window' use?
        using (System.Xml.XmlTextReader xmlReader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(fs))
        {
            reportViewer.Serialize(xmlReader); // cannot serialize anyway
        }
    }
}
```

The class `ReportViewerView` is legacy code on my end which is related to the Telerik class `ReportViewer`. The class `MyClass` is legacy code that's inherited from `Telerik.Reporting.Report`. I suspect that the `Windows` class holds my answer, but if it helps here is `ReportViewerView.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class ReportViewerView : Window
{
    public ReportViewerView(MyClass reportDoc, string title)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InstanceReportSource rs = new InstanceReportSource();
        rs.ReportDocument = reportDoc;
        this.reportViewer1.ReportSource = rs;
        this.Title = title;
    }
}
```

The class `MyClass` is a bit bulky to copy/paste in full, but it should do anything its parent `Telerik.Reporting.Report` can. Here's the short version:

```
partial class MyClass
{
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        // lot of stuff
    }

    private Telerik.Reporting.PageHeaderSection pageHeaderSection1;
    private Telerik.Reporting.DetailSection detail;
    private Telerik.Reporting.PageFooterSection pageFooterSection1;
    private Telerik.Reporting.TextBox textBox1;
    private Telerik.Reporting.TextBox TitleTB;
    private Telerik.Reporting.TextBox CustomerNameTB;
    private Telerik.Reporting.TextBox ReportDateTB;
    private string dateString
    {
        get { return DateTime.Now.ToString("g", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us")); }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered that rendering as a PDF may not be possible until the report has been rendered in a window? I don't know the implementation details of the component, but that's where I would start.

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34150934/how-to-print-a-windows-form-without-showing-displaying-it) can help. Create an image of form in background and print it as PDF.

Comment: @DanWilson The save feature of the `Window` class is a black box to me. I don't know how to look under the hood, even after looking at the documentation. The whole point of what I'm doing is that I don't want user input in the process, so I'm hesitant to say the window-opening is mandatory

Comment: @Sandeep Almost but not quite... I tried using `ReportViewerView` the way that person used `Form`, and got stuck when they tried `DrawToBitmap()`. That doesn't seem to be part of `Window` or `Telerik.Reporting.Report`.

Comment: In that case you can use [this](https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/reporting/styling-and-formatting-reports/details/saving-a-report-into-pdf-format-programmatically) to print `Telerik.Reporting.Report` directly to PDF rather than printing `ReportViewerView` window. Just a thought.

Comment: @Sandeep Yes!! That link is what I needed, in particular the method "reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", instanceReportSource, null)". It's really simply once you have `Telerik.Reporting.Report` as a byte[]